# In Angular 5, how do I execute an animation before routing to a different view?

Tags: angular, animation, view, angular5, router

I have a `view` & `controller`. When I click on a router link I would like to execute an exit animation before the view changes. Is it possible to delay the route link execution to allow for an exit animation to complete?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can do this with guard, the `CanDeactivate()` function, you can use a promise in this function, and resolve a true value after some seconds delay. And during this time, you can add some animation in your component.